# Ubuntu 14.04, Nvidia Driver 304.117 for 7600GT

Tags: boot, nvidia, 14.04, lightdm, ssd

I have a clean new installation on an SSD Drive of Ubuntu 14.04 with NVidia Driver 304.117
running.
After (very quick) boot I can hear that the login screen has started but no picture on my F-HD Monitor. 
By switching from LightDM to Terminal and back with CTRL+ALT F1 and CTRL+ALT F7 everything is fine and works like a charm. 
But how can I make ubuntu start as it should do directly into graphical Login and UI ?
Could it be that boot process is too ?! fast for my good old computer ?
Any idea ?
Regards
Makku

Comment: Since the last Ubuntu update it seems as if this problem has been solved. I saw in the Update Log that Ubuntu Greeter has been updated. Was this the point of the problem ? Does anybody know ?
Regards
makku71